# Aggregation of smoothing terms in GAMs

Tags: generalized-additive-model, smoothing

I have fitted a GAM model by using the R package `mgcv` via the expression

```r
model <- gam(formula, data, family = binomial())
```

The dimension of the basis used to represent the smooth terms is `k = 10`. Hence, having 9 covariates, I obtained 73 coefficients of the type `Intercept`, `s(X1).1, s(X1).2`,...,`s(X9).9` (coming from the command `coef(model)`).

My problem is to aggregate these coefficients into a single smoothed term, meaning that I want to compute `s(X1), s(X2),..., s(X9)`. How can I find these 9 quantities from the 73 coefficients? I took a look on the `te()`function, but I do not understand how it works and if it can be helpful.

Comment: I'm not understanding why you are wanting to "aggregate" the coefficients in the first place. The GAM already estimates a single smooth using the `s(x)` argument you outline. Perhaps you can explain what your purpose is for doing this. As far as the `te` function, this creates a tensor product interaction term which does not account for the main effects of each term independently.